# correct English name for specific car part

Tags: car, part-identification, mazda-3

I've spent hours to find what this part is called in English, could anyone please tell me ?
it's close to front wheel

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you point out the part you mean (e.g., by adding some lines directly in the image)?  It's not obvious if you mean the control arm or the bushing that it's connected to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the picture I would say a "lower control arm". It is also referred to as an "A" arm. The usual reasons for needing to change it are a worn ball joint if it is integrated into the arm and worn bushings, again if they are integrated into the assembly.

Comment: I found out that is was bushing, but bushing is part of the A arm so you're right thank you